# Make a very "white" black and white picture?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

I just saw the music video of BTS Mic Drop. I really like the style of this scene.

Does anyone know how to create this effect on any picture without masking the particular spots? And of course without being in a complete white photo studio.

I appreciate every help!

here is the video to the scene:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kTlv5_Bs8aw&t=220s

[image: example]

Answer (score 2):

These are sometimes called "high key" black and white images. The look starts in the camera by exposing for the foreground subject, but with a much brighter background, post processing can help the effect.  For a quality result, you can't really do this with any image. You have to start with a suitable image.

There are lots of photography tutorials and tips out there for high key work. If you google "high key photography" it'll get you started.

Answer (score 1):

Making any picture as light BW is impossible. But if there's well selected colors, they can be turned to nearly white in BW mixing. Let's assume all walls and floor are green and with well directed lights and material selections there's no green on the people and other objects which really are in studio. => you can treat the walls and floor separately.

A fake example (This popstar maybe hasn't as slick outlook, but with the same amount of AutoTune his singing would stay as well in pitch):

[image]

Desaturating the image gives this:

[image]

But color selective BW mix gives this:

[image]

Note1: In studio the light on the objects really must be able to supercede all green reflected light

Note2: Red objects could as well be mixed to black or white without spoiling the Popstar because there's no well saturated red in him.